# Reformat attribute before saving and return an error if needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, activerecord, formatting, youtube

I'm making a web-app in RoR

I have a model with YouTube video ID so I can use it to embed videos to the web-page.

It works well but I want to make it easier for admins to add videos, and I've already found out how to parse the video's ID from YouTube's URL, but now I thing about where to add it.

I want to notify the user that he have entered the wrong data like the validation does, but if I add some `parse_video_id` model method or add a `before_save` hook, how can I add an error to the object so I can then tell about it to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You add errors with:

```
errors.add(:attribute, message)
```

Comment: Wow, it's interesting. Will the `save` fail if there are errors? Or I have to write some more checks?

Comment: If any of the before_* callbacks return false the action is cancelled and save returns false

Comment: It should fail without you having to return false explicitly in this case, because AR sees that the model has errors. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html